# Python open() with minimal fluff variables

Tags: python, json, file-io

The intent is to look in a json file in the directory above the script and load up what it finds in that file. This is what I've got:

```
import os
import json

settings_file = '/home/me/foo/bar.txt'
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(settings_file))) # '/home/me'
target = os.path.join(root,'.extras.txt') # '/home/me/.extras.txt'
db_file= open(target)

databases = json.load(db_file) # works, returns object
databases2 = json.load(open(target)) # equivalent to above, also works
# try to condense code, lose pointless variables target and file
databases3 = json.load(open(os.path.join(root,'.extras.txt'))) # equivalent (I thought!) to above, doesn't work.
```

So... why doesn't the all-at-once, no holding variables version work? Oh, the error returned is (now in it's entirety):

```
$ ./json_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./json_test.py", line 69, in <module>
   databases =  json.load(open(os.path.join(root,'/.extras.txt')))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/.extras.txt'
```

And to satisfy S.Lott's well-intentioned advice... it doesn't matter what `target` is set to. The databases and databases2 populate correctly while databases3 does not. `target` exists, is readable and contains what json expects to see. I suspect there's something I don't understand about the nature of stringing commands together... I can make the code work, was just wondering why the concise (or complex?) version failed.

Comment: Are you sure there should be a dot before the e in extras.txt? That might be causing this problem.

Comment: are you sure root is correct the error suggests it is / or '' whilst you code gives something else

Comment: root comes back as '/home/me' which is expected and target comes back (when built explicitly) as '/home/me/.extras.txt', also expected.

Comment: @Wounder: Please (1) Update the question.  Never add comments to a question you own.  (2) Update the with the values of `target` for both working and non-working examples.  Please create a log that's very, very clear.  It's hard to follow what's wrong from the question.

Comment: As the code looks okay at first glance, it may help if you provide a complete failing interactive python session.

Comment: apparently you are trying to open ``/.extras.txt`` and not ``/home/me/.extras.txt`` despite what you may believe.  python isn't lying...

Comment: "The databases and databases2 populate correctly while databases3 does".  Not very easy for us to understand without a detailed, complete, easy-to-see log that shows code that works and variable values, and code that doesn't work with variable values.  Since your error message shows at least 69 lines of code -- which your snippet doesn't have -- we're left with one conclusion.  The actual code is **not** like the snippet.  Please prove that the **snippet** doesn't work.

Comment: try a `print root` or `print repr(root)` before every of the nonworking lines. Also try to successively reduce the intermediate variables, not all at once.

Comment: Using your now complete example, I cannot reproduce the error. Works for me (i.e. target is `/home/<user>/.extras.txt` and each opening succeeds).

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine, make sure referenced files are in the appropriate places. Given your code that includes target/file variable assignment, full path to `.extras.txt` is

> /home/me/.extras.txt

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
file = open(target, 'w')
```

because by default `open` will try to open the file in read mode (`r`) but you need to open it in `w` (write) mode if you want it to be created.

Also, I would not use the variable name `file` since it is also a type (`<type 'file'>`) in python.

You could add the write-mode flag to this line as well:

```
databases = json.load(open(os.path.join(root,'.extras.txt'), 'w'))
```

because from the limited information we have in the question it appears your `/.extras` file does not previously exist.

Final note, you are losing the handle to your open file in this line (since you are not storing it in your `file` variable):

```
databases = json.load(open(os.path.join(root,'.extras.txt')))
```

How do you intend to close the file when you're finished with it?

You could do this with a context manager (python >=2.6 or 2.5 if `import with_statement` used):

```
with open(os.path.join(root,'.extras.txt'), 'w') as f:
   databases = json.load(f)
```

which will take care of closing the file for you.

Comment: It's not a write, though. Just a read. And I tried making it explicit anyway with the flag... didn't change things.

I changed the variable name for file, which isn't what I was calling it... fail on my part for shooting for readability, sorry.